# How can I send a newsletter with xPages content?

Tags: java, newsletter, xpages, lotusscript

I have some content displayed using computed fields inside a repeat in my xpage.
I now need to be able to send out a newsletter (by email) every week with the content of this repeat. The content can be both plain text and html

My site is also translated into different languages so I need the code to be able to specify the language and return the content in that language.

I am thinking about creating a scheduled lotusscript or java agent that somehow read the content of the repeat. is this possible? if so, some sample code to get me started would be great

edit: the content is only available to logged in users

thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

Use a java agent, and instead of going to the content natively, do a web page open and open the page as if in a browser, then process the result.  (you could make a special version of the web page that hides all extraneous content as well if you wanted)

Comment: This is a lot of work but using something like jSoup may help in parsing the html returned from the webpage.

Comment: @DeclanLynch - this doesn't have to be so hard.
If you don't want to make a stripped down copy of the page, just embed some comment tags around what you want to pull out of the content.

' <!-- ***FIELD1 START*** --> your content  <!-- ***FIELD1 END*** -->'

Doing something like that would like you parse it with just basic string parsing in java as easy as pie.

Comment: I just tried this with jSoup and the parsing bit works great, but the content is not available until a user have logged in. I think the best thing for me now is to get the content from the notes documents. it is ok if all users get the same content.

Comment: Why not log the user in?  Doesn't xpages support the &login=1 tag?  You can pass session credentials in your web request.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

How is the data for the repeat evaluated? Can it be translated in to a lotusscript database.search?

If so then it would be best to forget about the actual xPage and concentrate on working out how to get the same data via LotusScript and then write your scheduled agent to loop through the document collection and generate the email that way.

Looking to the Xpage would generate a lot of extra work, you need to be authenticated as the user ( if the data in the repeat is different from one user to the next ) to get the exact same data that this particular user would see and then you have to parse the page to extract the data.

Comment: I can find the same data using a search but all the logic and translation is done in ssjs. All users are dominoanonymous as I use my own cookiebased login

Comment: Well then looks like jSoup and parsing the html might be the only option you have, I can't think of any other way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complicated enough newsletter that you want to do an Xpage and not build the html yourself in the agent, what you could do is build a single xpage that changes what's rendered based on a special query string, then in your agent get the html from a URLConnection and pass the html into the body of your email.

You could build the URL based on a view that shows documents with today's date.

Comment: true, but forgot to mention in the question that the content is only available to logged in users

Comment: You should be able to login via the URLConnection setup.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this by giving the user a teaser on what to read and give them a link to the full content.

Comment: Well, that is what I am trying to accomplish here. but I want the teaser to be based on the content of the site because I do not want to create the same markup in my agent.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Weihang Chens (my colleague) article about rendering an xPage as Mime and sending it as a mail.
http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/weihang/entry/render_a_xpages_programmtically_and_send_it_as_a_mail?lang=en_us

We got this working in house and it is very convenient.

He describes 3 different approaches to the problem.